# dropdown with combo box

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I am populating the options in dropdown list using mySQL output. These output values are ranked and I want to keep only top 20 values out of 100 in it. Most of the users are interested in only one of these top 20 items.  Occasionally a user may want to look something which is low ranked (21st, 22nd ... item).

I remember that I saw this in some website where if the desired option is not present, an option was there "not in the list". Selecting this option creates an input box where a user can write their value.

How this functionality can be acheived? Suggestion of any article pointing to similar problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to set up the combo box or how to skip the first X entries?

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you can do this fairly easily. Since no HTML was provided, I made a sample:

HTML:

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="0">Sample</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="test2" style="display:none;"/>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("test").onchange = function() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("test2");

    if (this.value == "other") {
        textbox.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        textbox.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DtRhk/